# Is there a way to make an image displayable in one website only?

Tags: web

I need to make a website with an private image inside of `<img />` tag, which mean you cannot view it any where outside that website. I need the image to not be displayed even if the user try to copy the src of the image and open it in another tab of the same browser.

Is it possible? If so, how can i achieve that?

Comment: nothing is going to be 100% but you could use a referrer header.

Comment: The thing is, that image is actually being rendered on the user's computer.  That means you had to sent the user everything needed to render it.  The only way you can protect such material against anything but trivial attacks is with the cooperation of the browser--and there's no DRM for images that I'm aware of.  Furthermore, there's no possible defense against simply copying the image off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. Long answer: not possible :-)

If you can get at it in *any* way (and you must be able to do that to get it to render in a browser), you can save it locally.

All someone would have to do is access it with a munged copy of a browser that saves all incoming data to disk.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to obfuscate the image so that the user won't be able to just copy and paste the URL, you can use the Javascript Image object to create a new image and drawImage to draw it into a canvas, however you'll still need to obtain the image data somehow, perhaps making an ajax request for the actual image on the server. However a really persistent user can inspect your javascript code and do some reverse engineering to get the image source.

A more naive user will just take an screenshot of the image and achieve the same effect.

So any attempt to try to prevent the user from copying the image is futile.